# unable to get quickbooks refresh token with php sdk

Tags: php, oauth-2.0, quickbooks

I'm trying to learn more about the quickbooks PHP SDK for generating access tokens. The following code below works perfectly. It will grab the last functioning access token that I stored to the database, assign it to the quickbooks dataservice, then grab 500 invoice records and print the invoice numbers:

```
<?php
require __DIR__.'/vendor/autoload.php';
require '../../../wp-config.php';
 
use QuickBooksOnline\API\DataService\DataService;
use QuickBooksOnline\API\Core\OAuth\OAuth2\OAuth2LoginHelper;
 
$con = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME);
 
if ($con->connect_errno) {
 
    printf("connection failed: %s\n", $con->connect_error());
    exit();
}
$sql = "SELECT * FROM wp_forbook ORDER BY create_date DESC LIMIT 1";
$result = $con->query($sql);
$row = $result->fetch_object();
$accessToken = unserialize($row->token);
$con->close();
 
// Create SDK instance
$config = include('config.php');
$dataService = DataService::Configure(array(
    'auth_mode' => 'oauth2',
    'ClientID' => $config['client_id'],
    'ClientSecret' =>  $config['client_secret'],
    'RedirectURI' => $config['oauth_redirect_uri'],
    'scope' => $config['oauth_scope'],
    'baseUrl' => $config['mode']
));
/*
$oauth2LoginHelper = new OAuth2LoginHelper($config['client_id'], $config['client_secret']);
$accessToken = $oauth2LoginHelper->refreshAccessTokenWithRefreshToken($accessToken->getRefreshToken());
*/
$dataService->updateOAuth2Token($accessToken);
$allInvoices = $dataService->FindAll('Invoice', 0, 500);
echo '<pre>';
if($allInvoices) {
  foreach ($allInvoices as $oneInvoice)
    echo $oneInvoice->DocNumber."\n";
} else {
  echo print_r($dataService->getLastError(),1);
}
echo '</pre>';
```

Again, the script I just pasted works perfectly.

However, if I enable these two lines to grab a refreshToken

```
$oauth2LoginHelper = new OAuth2LoginHelper($config['client_id'], $config['client_secret']);
$accessToken = $oauth2LoginHelper->refreshAccessTokenWithRefreshToken($accessToken->getRefreshToken());
```

then I see the error message:

```
QuickBooksOnline\API\Core\HttpClients\FaultHandler Object
(
    [context:QuickBooksOnline\API\Core\HttpClients\FaultHandler:private] => 
    [httpStatusCode:QuickBooksOnline\API\Core\HttpClients\FaultHandler:private] => 400
    [responseBody:QuickBooksOnline\API\Core\HttpClients\FaultHandler:private] => Unsupported OperationOperation Could not find resource for relative : /v3/company/query of full path: https://c50.sandbox.qbo.intuit.com/qbo50/v3/company/query?minorversion=57 is not supported.
    [helpMsg:QuickBooksOnline\API\Core\HttpClients\FaultHandler:private] => Invalid auth/bad request (got a 400, expected HTTP/1.1 20X or a redirect)
    [intuit_tid:QuickBooksOnline\API\Core\HttpClients\FaultHandler:private] => 1-5ffb7959-7079cde00c9068e3506236c7
    [intuitErrorType:QuickBooksOnline\API\Core\HttpClients\FaultHandler:private] => ValidationFault
    [intuitErrorCode:QuickBooksOnline\API\Core\HttpClients\FaultHandler:private] => 500
    [intuitErrorElement:QuickBooksOnline\API\Core\HttpClients\FaultHandler:private] => 
    [intuitErrorMessage:QuickBooksOnline\API\Core\HttpClients\FaultHandler:private] => Unsupported Operation
    [intuitErrorDetail:QuickBooksOnline\API\Core\HttpClients\FaultHandler:private] => Operation Could not find resource for relative : /v3/company/query of full path: https://c50.sandbox.qbo.intuit.com/qbo50/v3/company/query?minorversion=57 is not supported.
)
```

If I comment out the lines for refresh token again, press refresh on my webpage, then everything works again. In other words, my old tokens that come straight from the database still works even if I've executed `refreshAccessTokenWithRefreshToken()` in a previous session.

Why do my newly refreshed tokens cause the error message?

And why do old tokens issued within the past hour still work after a) I attempt to create refresh then b) see error message then c) disable refresh token code then d) refresh page?

How do I refresh access tokens properly?